# Where to get nftables?

Tags: kernel, firewall, nftables

As far as I understand the kernel facility `nftables` exists in the kernel that comes with Ubuntu 14.04. As is proven by the following two commands:

```
# grep -E '(NF_TABLES|NFT_)' /boot/config-$(uname -r)
CONFIG_NF_TABLES=m
CONFIG_NFT_EXTHDR=m
CONFIG_NFT_META=m
CONFIG_NFT_CT=m
CONFIG_NFT_RBTREE=m
CONFIG_NFT_HASH=m
CONFIG_NFT_COUNTER=m
CONFIG_NFT_LOG=m
CONFIG_NFT_LIMIT=m
CONFIG_NFT_NAT=m
CONFIG_NFT_COMPAT=m
CONFIG_NF_TABLES_IPV4=m
CONFIG_NFT_REJECT_IPV4=m
CONFIG_NFT_CHAIN_ROUTE_IPV4=m
CONFIG_NFT_CHAIN_NAT_IPV4=m
CONFIG_NF_TABLES_ARP=m
CONFIG_NF_TABLES_IPV6=m
CONFIG_NFT_CHAIN_ROUTE_IPV6=m
CONFIG_NFT_CHAIN_NAT_IPV6=m
CONFIG_NF_TABLES_BRIDGE=m
# lsmod |grep nf
nf_conntrack_ipv4      15012  1
nf_defrag_ipv4         12758  1 nf_conntrack_ipv4
nf_nat_ipv4            13263  1 iptable_nat
nf_nat                 21798  3 ipt_MASQUERADE,nf_nat_ipv4,iptable_nat
nf_conntrack           96976  5 ipt_MASQUERADE,nf_nat,nf_nat_ipv4,iptable_nat,nf_conntrack_ipv4
```

However, `apt-file search nftables` does not yield any results, nor does `apt-cache search nftables`.

So where can I get the new frontend for `nftables`, i.e. the `nftables` program matching the kernel modules?

Comment: I do not have any experience , but there is a how to here - https://home.regit.org/netfilter-en/nftables-quick-howto/ . I am not sure how much or how little of that is in the ubuntu repositories, my guess is not much =). If the link I gave you works, it can be converted into an answer.

Comment: Here is a ppa - https://launchpad.net/~xuzhen666/+archive/nftables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I too am looking for `nftables`, but as I understand, with 14.04 we have the 3.13 Kernel, and the 3.13 Kernel is the first version to get Nftables merged into it. Merging does not mean working, it just means the code is to a degree good and can be merged without creating other problems.

`iptables` is still in the 14.04 and on any other distro until `nftables` gets a stable release (More so than the 0.3 that was again merged with the Kernel). This, with the fact that nft user-space utils are not there yet will make the wait for nftables a bit longer.

With that in mind, if you don't want to wait you can use the `Nftables` step by step installation which includes git cloning the Linux kernel and settings other variables so that you can have `Nftables` working on your end. This information can be found in [regit.org](https://home.regit.org/netfilter-en/nftables-quick-howto/)

Aside from this, here is a [feature request](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1273337)

Answer (score 2):

Starting from the very beginning of the 2018 nftable framework is ready to use in  production environments. It supports 3/4 of the existing iptables features, although it provides new features that you cannot find in iptables.

Framework requires to have kernel >= 3.13, but running a newer kernel >= 4.10 is recommended. After

```
apt install nftables
```

Note: Make sure you don't run both `iptables` together with `nftables`.

There is a tool to convert from `iptables` configuration into `nftables` configuration:
https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Moving_from_iptables_to_nftables

Start by issuing the command `nft -a list ruleset` and start building from there. The list of rulesets will not be empty by default.

Comment: Could you expand on the "don't run both together" statement? Wouldn't something translate the `iptables` rules to `nftables` when you add such rules to `iptables`? Or do we have both set of tables as separate entities?

Comment: I guess I found [an answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/596493/can-nftables-and-iptables-ip6tables-rules-be-applied-at-the-same-time-if-so-wh) about that... It looks like it works in parallel, just some of the tools are not fully compatible.

Answer (score 1):

`apt-get install nftables`

```
root@forevernow ~ # cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS"
```